# Android authentication one time only with Apache Shiro

Tags: android, security, authentication, shiro

I am not very good in security so I hope to find some help. 
I am developing an android app which will connect to Apache Shiro for security (Authentication and authorization).
   At the first time it is easy to ask for username and password and register user. 
  I have here 2 problems:

```
   1- once the user register I don't want him to re login again. 
      so what exactly I should save on android App to authenticate the user 
      automatically next time he opens the Application. 

   2- If the user don't want to register he still can work on the 
      application, but I still want to remember this user with some of his 
      choices. In this case What i should save and what I should send to my 
      server to remember  (may be deviceID? phone No. etc...)
```

Comment: You should be able to use the cookies returned from the server to remember the state.  What have you tried already?

Comment: I know I can keep the connection between the server and client using SessionID or token etc. My main question what I need to save on the client to authenticate him next time automatically and how to save these information